# File on doc root won't change unless path changes

Tags: files, apache2

I found strange problem about my server/ apache.

I make change of content of some files, lets say, on `var/www/test-app/index.html`. when I visit the browser: `http://localhost/test-app/index.html`, the change does not appear, It just like it was not changed at all.

but, if I change the folder, to `var/www/test-app2/index.html`, the change appears properly.

What could be the issue ??

Note that everything normal again if i restart the apache

Answer (score 0):

HTML files are liable to browser caching unless you disable it. Try checking the Expires and Cache-Control headers in the response from the server, via your browser's developer tools.

You can also visit the URL with a unique get parameter, like ?1 or ?2 on the end.

Comment: I dont think that this is browser issue becouse it happen in all browser, also.. it normal again if I restart the server(apache)

Comment: Did you check the headers though?